# Reading in 2 Arrays from a file

Tags: python

How would I read in from a file and separate it into an array?
Example
inside the file

test1:test1

test2:test2

read into array line by line
user[] pass[]

```
with open("acc.txt") as f:

   for line in f:
       username, password = line.split(':')
       content_array.append(line)
       print(username)
```

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Comment: We would need to know the format of the file (json, csv) to give you a good answer

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? There are plenty of resources available on this, in what way do they not address this particular situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is probably the best data structure this, here are two ways to do it:

```
def open_txt(path):
    with open(path) as file:
        return file.read()

acc = open_txt('./acc.txt')

acc_dict = {line.split(':')[0]: line.split(':')[1]
            for line in acc.splitlines()}
acc_dict_list = [{'name': line.split(':')[0],
                  'pass': line.split(':')[1]}
                 for line in acc.splitlines()]

print(f'acc_dict: {acc_dict}')
print(f'acc_dict_list: {acc_dict_list}')
```

Input (acc.txt):

```
user1:pass654321
user2:pass123456789
user3:pass987654321459
```

Output:

```
acc_dict: {'user1': 'pass654321', 'user2': 'pass123456789', 'user3': 'pass987654321459'}
acc_dict_list: [{'name': 'user1', 'pass': 'pass654321'}, {'name': 'user2', 'pass': 'pass123456789'}, {'name': 'user3', 'pass': 'pass987654321459'}]
```